Supernatural episode where Dean and Sam are in a plane for a short period of time
A while ago, I watched a random episode of Supernatural. I can't remember the episode nor the season, not even much about it. I can only remember a few details (not in order):

A crib leaking black goop, presumably ectoplasm
A man covered in blood in his bed
Dean and Sam in a plane for a short period of time

Which episode is this? Is this even an existing episode, or did I watch a compilation or something?
Also, as I'm not sure whether #1 and #2 are incorrect but I'm positive about #3, can someone list all Supernatural episodes in which Sam and Dean are in a plane?
If it helps, I watched it in 2013/2014.

It seems we have enough details to identify that episode. But feel free to add more details as you recall. Though I didn't watch the show. Maybe someone around can find it.

The short time on the plane might hint to Sympathy for the devil:

Just as a blinding light and sound force them to their knees, they are transported into an airplane flying over Ilchester, Maryland, where Lucifer was confined.

The only other candidate I can come up with would be Phantom Traveller, which has more airplane-time than you hint at though. It is about a demon causing airplanes to crash.
Luckily for your request, the Winchesters don't tend to fly much!

I'm a Supernatural fangirl, so I can definitely help here. All three scenes you describe take place in Season 5, Episode 1, "Sympathy for the Devil" (original air date in 2009). The scenes are not consecutive, however. Did you see them back-to-back?
If you saw them all together, you might have seen a "The Road So Far" section at the beginning of another episode. Each show begins with a brief collection of clips from previous episodes. 

Yeah they're not in order. Edited.
